# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() throwing RuntimeException while not in Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, runtimeexception

When I'm trying to get default bluetooth adapter while i'm NOT in Activity, but in `TimerTask` (created inside `Service`) by using:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception while invoking java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

My application do not have any activity - so is there any possibility to get this adapter away from Activity?

Comment: See Android response to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16587

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Android and still exists in Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

To workaround this and be able to call `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` from a worker thread (e.g. AsyncTask), all you have to do is call `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` once on the main UI thread (e.g. inside the `onCreate()` of your current activity).

The RuntimeException is only thrown during initialization, and `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` only initializes the first time you call it. Subsequent calls to it will succeed, even in background threads.

Comment: Any links on a bug's page?

Answer (score 6):

Calling `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` in the `UI` thread works, but is not very practical. I have tried the workaround with a fake Activity, but since I hate such workarounds, I decided to READ what the error message really says and it is nothing more than that the thread didn't call `Looper.prepare()`.

So calling `Looper.prepare()` just before calling `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` should solve the problem anywhere, not just in a UI thread.

Works fine for me so far.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea unless you actually intend your worker thread to be a Looper.

Comment: Note that you should check whether the current thread has already called `Looper.prepare()` like this: `if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            {
              Looper.prepare();
            }` Otherwise, you'll get a `RuntimeException` as this function may only be called once per thread.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how correct it is, but I added this wrapper function:

```
static boolean m_calledLooperAlready = false;

BluetoothAdapter getDefaultBluetoothAdapter() {
    if ( !m_calledLooperAlready ) {
        try  {
            android.os.Looper.prepare();
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        m_calledLooperAlready = true;
    }
    return BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}
```

... and replaced all occurrences of `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` with `getDefaultBluetoothAdapter()`. This works ok for me on: 2.2.1, 2.3.3, 4.0.4, 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Beware of a gotcha that exists in 2.3.x, but which has been fixed in 4.x:  if you call `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` on any thread other than the main application thread, that thread must call `Looper.prepare()` and also subsequently `Looper.loop()`.

Failing to do so will cause at least one problem that I ran into: `accept()` will succeed the first time you try to connect, but then not succeed on successive attempts, even after using `close()` on the ServerSocket.

This happens because in the older implementation of BluetoothAdapter, the cleanup of the SDP entry occurs by way of a message posted to a handler created on the thread where `getDefaultAdapter()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kocus there is no any method called `getDefault()` in `BluetoothAdapter calss` .
It should be `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();`

[follow this link for more information.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

Comment: Your example is for getting `BluetoothAdapter` from `Activity`. This is NOT what I want.

Comment: yes but i think BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() can't be called from the worker Thread . It should be from UI thread.

Comment: Do not really understand what is fake Activity. Could you provide some code.