# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() throw RuntimeException: Stub!

Tags: android

I run my server bluetooth on my desktop windows and i got RuntimeException: Stub! when i launch it;

Excactly when i call: BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() the code stop!

Anyone knows any alternative class to BluetoothAdapter for desktop bluetooth  service?

Comment: Here is same issue and some solutions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920578/bluetoothadapter-getdefault-throwing-runtimeexception-while-not-in-activity

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are running in the emulator: I do not believe the emulator has a working Bluetooth implementation, which is why you are getting the stub exception.

As far as I can tell there is currently no way to run the Bluetooth functionality in the emulator: you will have to use a device.

Comment: If the emulator wouldn't have bluetooth, getDefaultAdapter() should return null.